# What does this line of code do?

Tags: java

```
String usage = "IndexHTML [-create] [-index <index>] <root_directory>";
```

What does this line do in my `IndexHTML.java` file?

Comment: Don't know either. What does IndexHTML.java ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be the one to tell us? Is it not **your** indexHTML.java?

Answer (score 11):

It defines either a local variable or a field (depending on its location) named `usage` of type `String` with the value `"IndexHTML [-create] [-index <index>] <root_directory>"`.

It looks like it's meant for a short error/help message about how to run the class. It means that the class (when started from the command line) takes an optional `-create` flag, an optional `-index` option with an argument and that you need to specify the root directory.

Comment: I am told in my lucene demo to run the following command on the command line "java org.apach.apache.lucene.demo.IndexHTML -creat -index /usr/local/lib ..", but it always brings me a NoClassDeffoundError:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apach/apache/lucene/demo/IndexHTML
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apach.apache.lucene.demo.IndexHTML
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:19)...
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)

Comment: @user544006: that means that the class is not on your classpath.

Comment: How do i get the class on my classpath? In the tutorial it asks me to create classpaths to the jar files which i have done using this command: 
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562\ Project/lucene-3.0.3/lucene-core-3.0.3.jar. 
The demo does not mention creating classpaths to that online file (org.apach.apache.lucene.demo.IndexHTML) which i used in the demo.

Comment: I tried CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:org.apach.apache.lucene.demo.IndexHTML, but im still getting ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Please stop doing programming by accident! Learn [how to manipulate your CLASSPATH and what it means](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)! You need to add the .jar file or directory that contains the directories/file `org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexHTML.class` to your classpath.

Comment: I have set another CLASSPATH to the /lucene/src directory which contains that IndexFiles.java file, but still getting the same error! I dont know what else I can do.

Comment: @user: your classpath mast point to the directory containing the (directory containing the) `.class` files! Java doesn't execute `.java` files.

Comment: I changed the classpath to point to that specific directory,"CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562_Project/lucene-3.0.3/src/demo/org/apache/lucene/demo". Still getting error. Im still getting an error when i run, "java /Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562_Project/lucene-3.0.3/src/demo/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexHTML -create -index /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/"

Comment: @user: please open a separate question for this and describe your environment specifically. The comments are **not** the right place for this (also you'll get help from other people as well).

Comment: Ok, il open up a seperate question with more detail. Thanks.

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970557/mac-indexing-and-classpath-problems-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score 0):

If you search around you will find also an if checking the contents and size of your args array.