# Mac Indexing and CLASSPATH problems - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, macos, lucene, classpath

System properties:
Java 1.6
Mac OSX version 10
Ant 1.8

Scenario:  I am working on my final year project which is to create a website which uses Lucene to search my website and my database. I am working through lucene demos here
http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/demo.html
which talks about classpath 
http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/demo3.html and a web example

I have created a .bash_profile file in my home directory /Users/philhunter/ which sets my classpaths:

```
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562_Project/lucene-3.0.3/lucene-core-3.0.3.jar
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562_Project/lucene-3.0.3/lucene-demo-3.0.3.jar
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562_Project/lucene-3.0.3/src/demo/org/apache/lucene/demo
```

When i try and run the commands it asks on the command line i am getting ClassDefNotFoundError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562_Project/lucene-3/0/3/src/demo/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexHTML
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .Users.philhunter.Desktop.COM562_Project.lucene-3.0.3.src.demo.org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexHTML
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

The command line command is:

```
java /Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562_Project/lucene-3.0.3/src/demo/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexHTML -create -index /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/
```

which should index my website files. That indexHTML file is a java file in that last classpath directory above. Anyone know why I am getting theat error!?

Comment: does a .class file exist in the /Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562_Project/lucene-3.0.3/src/demo/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexHTML location?

Answer (score 0):

I think the path you're passing is the problem. Try adding the following to your bash script

```
cd /Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562_Project/lucene-3.0.3/src/demo/
java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexHTML -create -index /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/
```

The problem is that when you run

```
java /Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562_Project/lucene-3.0.3/src/demo/org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexHTML
```

you are telling java run the class in the package

```
Users.philhunter.Desktop.COM562_Project.lucene-3.0.3.src.demo.org.apache.lucene.demo
```

.

Comment: Another problem might be the 3rd line of the class path, that it's pointing to the path where you might have the .java classes, rather that the "root" package.

Comment: I changed to that directory but still getting the errors. As for the 3rd classpath, yes its pointing to the IndexHTML directory that the file is. What is the "root package"? Should i put another classpath in to point to the Lucene folder with everything in it? (I was told i should be specific with the directory)